# Required to specify id in factory for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a factory that creates an association after create. I doesn't work unless I specify the foreign key. Even though the foreign key is specified in the model. Is this normal? If not how can I fix it?

#### factory

```
trait :with_csr do
  after :create do |cc|
    cc.csrs << create(:csr, signed: true, certificate_content_id: cc.id)
  end
end
```

#### certificate_content model

```
has_many :csrs, dependent: :destroy
```

#### csr model

```
belongs_to  :certificate_content, touch: true, foreign_key: 'certificate_content_id'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there an ActiveRecord validation error being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an order-of-operations issue. FactoryBot's `#create` will immediately persist the new `csr` record to the database, *before* the `<<` operator attempts to create the relationship between the records.

Try changing the `create` to `build`, and remove the `certificate_content_id: cc.id`. `build` should instantiate, but not persist, the record. And then the `<<` will create the relationship and persist the record as well.

*Edit*: alternatively, you could keep the `#create` and just remove the `<<`:

```
after :create do |cc|
  create(:csr, signed: true, certificate_content_id: cc.id)
end
```

That would work just as well.